# remote server not worked at navodaya sammithi

Tags: javascript

Unable to connect to the remote server at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at ECSAuaInterfaceExApi.ECSAuaInterfaceExApiHelper.PHAvIPcIIPLvUh8K75j(Object ) at ECSAuaInterfaceExApi.ECSAuaInterfaceExApiHelper.aw8D71cfy(String ) at ECSAuaInterfaceExApi.ECSAuaInterfaceExApiHelper.TN4fEStTS[PQS8ErhEaTOwOar4xQ](String , Object ) at ECSAuaInterfaceExApi.ECSAuaInterfaceExApiHelper.GenerateOtp(String requestId, String uid, String txnId, String consent, Boolean sendSMS, Boolean sendEmail, String udf1, String udf2, String udf3, String udf4, String udf5, String udf6, String udf7, String udf8, String udf9, String udf10) at NVSMVCApp.Controllers.IndexController.Registration(pRegistrationDetailPhase1and2 cls, HttpPostedFileBase fileCertificate, FormCollection collection) in D:\Sandeep\NVSMVCApplatest\NVSMVCApp\Controllers\IndexController.cs:line 283

not worked
did not work navodaya

Answer (score 0):

This title does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it clearly summarizes your problem and uses proper grammar. You can put details in the body of your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).